# how to identify advertisement links

Tags: url, iframe, malware, ads

How can I identify ad links from a website? I am doing a research on malvertising. As a part of that, I need to extract all the advertisement urls from the website. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Of course it’s impossible to correctly identify all URLs.)

You could make use of the filter lists of various [ad filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_filtering) tools. They typically contain absolute URLs (submitted by the community) and strings that often appear in such URLs.

For example, *AdBlock Plus* hosts some [filter lists](https://adblockplus.org/en/subscriptions).

Example from [EasyList](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) ([big text file](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt)):

> - `&adbannerid=`
> - `.com/js/adsense`
> - `/2013/ads/*`
> - `/60x468.`
> - `/ad-rotator-`